# Prove: $\sin(\theta) - \sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta) = \sin^3(\theta)$. Help please? I'm lost.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove:  $\sin(\theta) - \sin(\theta)\cos^2(\theta) = \sin^3(\theta)$.

Can someone show me how to prove this? Do I use the Pythagorean Identity to prove it?

I will be forever grateful. Thanks!

- Do I factor $\sin(\theta)$ out of both terms on the left side of the equal sign
  and then divide both sides by $\sin(\theta)$?

Comment: $1-\cos^2\theta=\ldots$

Comment: I don't get it. It's a perfectly valid question! It doesn't matter if it's an easy one, Stack Exchange is for asking! It doesn't matter the question, but this doesn't deserve to be downvoted! (It would have -2 but I upvoted)

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite
$$\sin\theta-\sin\theta\cos^2\theta=\sin\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)$$
Remember that $1-\cos^2\theta=\sin^2\theta$ and then plug it in:
$$
\sin\theta-\sin\theta\cos^2\theta=\sin\theta(1-\cos^2\theta)=
\sin\theta\cdot\sin^2\theta=\sin^3\theta.
$$

Note: there's no need to divide by $\sin\theta$ which is a very dangerous thing to do, because you don't know whether it's zero or not. In this *particular* case it makes no real difference, because if $\sin\theta=0$ the identity clearly holds. It could be in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\sin(\theta)(1 - \cos^2(\theta)) = \sin^3(\theta)$$

Comment: is that how to solve it?

Comment: Divide each side by Sin.......

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify:

$$\sin{\theta}-\sin{\theta}\cos^{2}{\theta}=\sin^{3}{\theta}$$
$$1-\cos^{2}{\theta}=\sin^{2}{\theta}$$
$$1=\sin^{2}{\theta}+\cos^{2}{\theta}$$

And that being a trigonometric identity makes your theorem proved (The case where $\sin{\theta}=0$ is trivial to solve).

Comment: You aren't allowed to divide by $\sin\theta$.

Comment: @egreg Why? Is there anything wrong with my proof?

Comment: @egreg: Ok, so take the case where $\sin \theta = 0$ separately.  In this case the identity is trivially satisfied.

Comment: @AnonymousPi Yes, as it stands it's wrong. Not blatantly wrong, but subtly.

Comment: @egreg Why? Nate already said $\sin{\theta}=0$ is trivial!

Comment: @AnonymousPi It *has* to be observed.

Comment: @egreg I don't think you are being clear. Stop critizicing my question!

Comment: @AnonymousPi What he's getting at is that you failed to note that if $\sin\theta\neq 0$ ,then you can do what you did; if you don't mention this, then there are times where you're dividing by zero, and that's why your solution as it currently stands is _subtly_ incorrect.

Comment: @ChristopherToni: No, the proof is completely correct as it is. In fact the only thing missing is the direction of the implications: they go $\Leftarrow$, not $\Rightarrow$. The implication $ab = ac \Leftarrow b = c$ is always true, even when $a = 0$.

Answer (score -1):

sin(θ)−sin(θ)cos2(θ)=sin3(θ)

First, subtract sin(θ) from both sides.

-sin(θ)*cos2(θ)=sin3(θ)-sin(θ)

Now, divide both sides by -sin(θ). Mind the - sign.

Cos2(θ)= [sin3(θ)-sin(θ)]/-sin(θ)

Factor the top by grouping. Pull out a -sin(θ) from both sides. Mind the signs.

Cos2(θ)=-sin(θ)(-sin2(θ)+1)-sin(θ)

Cancel out -sin(θ) from the top and bottom

cos2(θ)=-sin2(θ)+1

Move the 1

cos2(θ)=1-sin2(θ)

Take the square root of both sides

Cos(θ)= +-√1-sin2(θ)

Bam. Trig identity!